# How to convert my CommonJS module to UMD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, amd, umd

I'm new to UMD and AMD. I've written a JS library in Browserify and I've just came across UMD. My understanding is if I include a piece of code for every module, my module should be able to be used in CommonJs and AMD.

Here's my sample Module.

./src/main.js

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'; // from npm install js-cookie
import lib1 from './lib/lib1';

window.MyModule = function MyModule(options) {
  let lib1;
  function methodA() {

  }

  return {
    methodA: methodA
  };

  (function init() {
    lib1 = lib1();
    // Some initialization code.
  })();
};

module.exports = window.MyModule;
```

./lib/lib1.js

```
module.exports = (options) => {
  function func1() {

  }

  return {
    func1: func1
  };
}
```

And this is how I pack everything using browserify

```
browserify src/main.js --outfile dist/main.js --debug
```

And when I want to use this module I just do.

```
<script src="//main.js"></script>
```

My question is, how do I convert my module to be UMD so it can be included in both CommonJS and AMD.

Comment: Have a look at the `--standalone` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `deamdify`, `es6ify` and `deglobalify` to do what you're after.

```
npm install deamdify es6ify deglobalify
browserify -t deamdify -t es6ify -t deglobalify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Source: http://dontkry.com/posts/code/browserify-and-the-universal-module-definition.html

Comment: I tried putting deamdify into transform but the generated file is the same as without it.

Comment: I thought doing transform using deamdify is just for the module to consume AMD module?